# How to compare the items of two list-boxes and copy the unique items to new list-box

Tags: c#, listbox, duplicates, text-files

I have three list boxes. The left and the middle list-box have some items. I want to compare the items in the left and middle list-box. I want to move the unique items to right side list-box from middle list-box and I want an expression handle.

I tried do it with the code underneath.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    List<string> FileNames = null;


    private void Btn_FileFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (FolderBrowserDialog FBDfolder = new FolderBrowserDialog())
        {

            if (FBDfolder.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                lbl_FolderPath.Text = FBDfolder.SelectedPath;
                FileNames = Directory.GetFiles(FBDfolder.SelectedPath).ToList();
                lstbx_filefolder.DataSource = FileNames.Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f)).ToList();
                lbl_NoOfFolderItems.Text = lstbx_filefolder.Items.Count.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    private void Btn_TextFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog textfile = new OpenFileDialog {
            Filter = "text (*.txt)|*.txt"
    };

        if (textfile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            lbl_filepath.Text = textfile.FileName;

            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(lbl_filepath.Text);
            lstbx_textfile.Items.AddRange(lines);
            lbl_NoOfItems.Text = lstbx_textfile.Items.Count.ToString();

        }

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btn_RemoveDuplicates_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var listboxfile = lstbx_filefolder.Items;
        var listboxtext = lstbx_textfile.Items;

        foreach (var itm in listboxfile)
        {
            if (listboxtext.Contains(itm)) listboxtext.Remove(itm); 
        }
    }

    private void btn_clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstbx_filefolder.DataSource = null;
        //lstbx_filefolder.Items.Clear();
        lstbx_textfile.DataSource = null;
        lstbx_textfile.Items.Clear();

    }
}

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When working with collections you could in many cases use Linq for these taks.

The first step in solving your problem would be to combine the lists into a single list
The next step would be to use Linq to get the unique string values from the list, this while assigning the result of the Linq query to a new List.

By using `Distinct()` the duplicate items are removed. Resulting in something like this:

```
private void btn_RemoveDuplicates_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var itemCollection = new List<string>();
    itemCollection.AddRange(lstbx_filefolder.Items);
    itemCollection.AddRange(lstbx_textfile.Items);


    var uniqueCollection = itemCollection.Distinct().ToList();

   // todo assign the values in the uniqueCollection to the source of the right listbox.
   `rightListBox`.Datasource = uniqueCollection; 
}
```

Comment: The items in the left and middle list-boxes will not be altered, their values wil not change. The remove duplicates method will create a list with the unique values. Then you can assign the list with unique items to the right list-box.